# Unable to connect to data source - solved by FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient usage

Tags: c#, odbc, firebird

I'm trying to connect to an Firebird DB programmatically via ODBC.
I've installed the ODBC driver and tested the connection :

[image: Test]

But I'm still running into an error:

> ERROR [08004] [ODBC Firebird Driver]Unable to connect to data source:
> library 'C:/Program Files (x86)/HK-Software/IBExpert/FBCLIENT.DLL'
> failed to load
> ERROR [01S00] [ODBC Firebird Driver]Invalid connection string
> attribute

Comment: Given you're defining a 32-bit ODBC connection, make sure that the referenced fbclient.dll is 32-bit. It is likely the file you currently reference is a 64-bit fbclient.dll (it's in Program Files, not in Program Files (x86), and 32-bit Windows should be pretty uncommon these days)

Comment: However, given you're tagging C#, why even use ODBC. Use the FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient NuGet package instead.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel IBExpert is 32-buit Delphi application, however it does not have fbclient in it, instead it has FB 2.5 Embedded as "c:\Program Files (x86)\HK-Software\IBExpert\IBEUDB\fbembed.dll"  - hence i believe topicstarter's fbclient does not beling to IBExpert and was copied there by some 3rd party

Comment: @JonteSE - use tools like ntCore.com CFF Explorer or FileList (http://totalcmd.net/plugring/fileinfo.html) to 1) detect the architecture of the fbclient.dll (Win32/x86 or Win64/x64 or maybe any other) and 2) check the dependency tree (required DLLs) of it. Also check in Task Manager whether your applicatoin is Win32 or Win64 or some other arch, and then if it matches one of the DLL

Comment: @MarkRotteveel - thanks, got it working with FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirldClient.